# How do you retrieve mean values from a `gmdistribution` object?

Tags: probability, matlab, gaussian

Running the function:

```
obj = gmdistribution.fit(X,n)
```

outputs an `obj` of class `gmdistribution`. However, I would like to output an n x 1 matrix of means, what commands should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `gmdistribution` object - `obj`, you can get the `nx1` mean vector by simply referencing that field as follows:

```
meanVector=obj.mu;
```